# I am creating a shell script by using grep to track a log

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Instead of printing out this,

```
============ Normal grep location of the files ============
ems_inet1/SystemOut1.log
ems_rpt1/SystemOut_19.09.09_23.00.00.log
ems_rpt1/SystemOut_19.09.11_23.00.00.log
============ Compress grep location of the files ============
ems_rpt1/SystemOut_19.05.12_23.00.00.log.gz
```

I want to print out this instead,

```
============ Normal grep location of the files ============
ems_inet1 - SystemOut1.log
ems_rpt1 - SystemOut_19.09.09_23.00.00.log
ems_rpt1 - SystemOut_19.09.11_23.00.00.log
============ Compress grep location of the files ============
ems_rpt1 - SystemOut_19.05.12_23.00.00.log.gz
```

I does not want to have a slash and i want to separate it by a " - " dash

here is the my code

```
echo "============ Normal grep location of the files ============"
grep -Erl "${input}" ems*/SystemOut*.log
#
echo "============ Compress grep location of the files ============"
zgrep -Erl "${input}" ems*/SystemOut*.log.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -Erl "${input}" ems*/SystemOut*.log | sed 's#/# - #'
```